# Is it "I've heard the story told many times" or "I've heard the story being told many times"?

Tags: grammar

I've learned that we use a bare infinitive or present participle after see, hear, watch. What happens when the object after these verbs are in a passive situation?

For example, is it "I've heard the story told many times", or "I've heard the story being told many times"?

Comment: "I've heard the story **(having been)** told many times" -- with the **(having been)** elided.

Comment: ...Yes, it was a short story.

Comment: Either version is fine, though the second is arguably a bit redundant.

Answer (score 0):

Compare the following:

> heard it move (I heard a sound that told me that it had moved)
>
> heard it moving (I heard it while it was moving)
>
> heard it moved (I heard a sound that told me that it had been moved)
>
> heard it being moved (I heard it while it was being moved)

"heard it told" and "heard it being told" correspond to the third and fourth case above.

I wouldn't say that "heard it moved" is "heard it [having been] moved", since I have never heard it used that way and native speakers (who are not linguists) will probably never associate it like this. (certainly not "heard it having been used"!)